# creating a list / array from a text file or csv file using bash

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I'm trying to wrote a small shell script to parse a simple CSV file (just one column) and assign the value in each value to a variable that needs to be an array / list.

Sample file:

```
Title_ID
123
456
789
000
```

Need the script to parse the file and output the results to a variable called title such that 
`echo ${title[1]}` returns **456**

Here is my current script

```
while read line; do
temp_title[$i]="$line"
i=$((i++))
done < ./title_master_list.csv
```

I keep getting the following error **zsh: temp_title: assignment to invalid subscript rang**

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: sorry about that, I might have messed up the formatting on your post, just revert back...

Comment: You need to define `i` before the loop, `i=1` but Is this a `zsh` or a `bash` question?

Comment: Your title says using bash, but that error says you're using zsh...

Comment: my apologies, i was running it using zsh not bash

Answer (score 2):

From [`man zshparam`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Array-Subscripts):

> The elements are numbered beginning with 1, unless the `KSH_ARRAYS` option is set in which case they are numbered from zero.

So, the problem you're having is because you're trying to use indexing starting at 0, not 1. Use:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh
typeset -a temp_title
i=1
while IFS= read -r line; do
    temp_title[i++]="$line" # Note the postincrement in the index expression
done < ./title_master_list.csv
echo "${temp_title[1]}"
```

But there's better ways to do it, without using a loop, using `zsh` [parameter expansion flags](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion):

```
temp_title=("${(@f)"$(<./title_master_list.csv)"}")
```

This splits the file up at newlines into an array.

It can also be done with a single `read`:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -A temp_title < ./title_master_list.csv
```

---

For completeness's sake, other loop based approaches:

Setting the option to use 0-based arrays:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh
setopt KSH_ARRAYS
typeset -a temp_title
i=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
    temp_title[i++]="$line"
done < ./title_master_list.csv
echo "${temp_title[0]}"
```

Don't use indexes, use `+=()` to append to the array:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh
typeset -a temp_title
while IFS= read -r line; do
    temp_title+=("$line")
done < ./title_master_list.csv
echo "${temp_title[1]}"
```

When using `bash` instead of `zsh`, use the `mapfile` builtin to read a file into an array:

```
mapfile -t temp_title < ./title_master_list.csv
```

Really old versions might have to use:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a temp_title < ./title_master_list.csv
```

(Similar to the `zsh` version, but uses a lowercase `-a`)

Comment: When scripting for bash, use `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a array_var <file` rather than `mapfile` because there is a wider support for `read -a` than for `mapfile`.

Comment: @LéaGris If you're using a version of bash too old to have `mapfile`... my sympathies.

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to do the trick! A couple of follow up questions regarding arrays if you have a minute - 1) do array need to be explicitly declared? 2) is typeset -a the only way to declare an array?

Comment: @raja The [documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Array-Parameters) reveals all.